# Codeigniter Having undefined index

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to access a table by referencing another table ID and by doing so I created first a foreach loop to retrieve the first table data then give its ID reference to the second table. I have done it in my other function but I don't know in this function prompts me that it's undefined index. Here is my model:

```
function retrieve_Sched($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('schedule');
    $this->db->where('EmpID',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

and here is the controller function:

```
foreach($data['result'] as $val)
{
    $data['schedule'] = $this->DBmodel->retrieve_Sched($val['EmpID']);

    if($data['schedule'] == false)
    {
        $consTimeIn = '05:30';
        $consLunchOut = '10:50';
        $consLunchIn = '13:00';
        $consTimeOut = '17:00';
    }
    else
    {
        $consTimeIn = $data['schedule']['TimeFrom'];
        $consLunchOut = $data['schedule']['LunchOut'];
        $consLunchIn = $data['schedule']['LunchIn'];
        $consTimeOut = $data['schedule']['TimeTo']; 
    }
}
```

This is the error that I get:

> ERROR - 2016-05-23 09:57:02 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: TimeFrom C:\xampp\htdocs\TMS\application\controllers\tms.php 482
> ERROR - 2016-05-23 09:57:02 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: LunchOut C:\xampp\htdocs\TMS\application\controllers\tms.php 483
> ERROR - 2016-05-23 09:57:02 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: LunchIn C:\xampp\htdocs\TMS\application\controllers\tms.php 484
> ERROR - 2016-05-23 09:57:02 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: TimeTo C:\xampp\htdocs\TMS\application\controllers\tms.php 485
> ERROR - 2016-05-23 09:58:41 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: TimeFrom C:\xampp\htdocs\TMS\application\controllers\tms.php 482
> ERROR - 2016-05-23 09:58:41 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: LunchOut C:\xampp\htdocs\TMS\application\controllers\tms.php 483
> ERROR - 2016-05-23 09:58:41 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: LunchIn C:\xampp\htdocs\TMS\application\controllers\tms.php 484
> ERROR - 2016-05-23 09:58:41 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: TimeTo C:\xampp\htdocs\TMS\application\controllers\tms.php 485

Comment: Can you var_dump $data['schedule'] just before the line 482 ?

Comment: print_r($data['schedule']);die;before if condition..it might be issue of wrong key or you have to use "->" to access specific key

Comment: I var_dump and print_r and it contains data. I already tried what Kunal suggested but I am having Trying to get property of non-object error...

Comment: I am trying now to put them inside another for loop and access them outside of it....

Comment: I think should I create separate function one for the default and one for the scheduled one......

Comment: I am now adding a third if statement and see if its solved the problem....

Comment: Yes adding another conditional statement solves my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves my problem:

```
if($data['result'] == false)
    {
        echo 'Sorry files have already been processed';
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($data['result'] as $val)
        {
            $data['check'] = $this->DBmodel->check_Sked($val['EmpID']);

            if($data['check'] == false)
            {
                $consTimeIn = "05:30";
                $consLunchOut = "10:50";
                $consLunchIn = "13:00";
                $consTimeOut = "17:00";
            }
            else
            {
                $data['schedule'] = $this->DBmodel->retrieve_sched($val['EmpID'],$val['ValidDate']);

                if($data['schedule'] == false)
                {
                    $consTimeIn = "05:30";
                    $consLunchOut = "10:50";
                    $consLunchIn = "13:00";
                    $consTimeOut = "17:00";
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach($data['schedule'] as $value)
                    {
                        $conTimeIn = $value['TimeFrom'];
                        $consTimeOut = $value['TimeTo'];

                        if($value['LunchOut'] == NULL || $value['LunchOut'] == "")
                        {
                            $consLunchOut = @date('H:i',@strtotime($consTimeIn,'+4 hour'));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $consLunchOut = $value['LunchOut'];
                        }

                        if($value['LunchIn'] == NULL || $value['LunchIn'] == "")
                        {
                            $consLunchIn = @date('H:i',@strtotime($consTimeIn,'+6 hour'));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $consLunchIn = $value['LunchIn'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

from your controller, the function that you use is returning array. 
`$data['schedule'] = $this->DBmodel->retrieve_Sched($val['EmpID']);`

try give a shot :

```
foreach($data['result'] as $val)
            {
                $data['schedule'] = $this->DBmodel->retrieve_Sched($val['EmpID']);

                if($data['schedule'] == false)
                {
                    $consTimeIn = '05:30';
                    $consLunchOut = '10:50';
                    $consLunchIn = '13:00';
                    $consTimeOut = '17:00';
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach($data['schedule'] as $schedule)
                        {
                            $consTimeIn = $schedule['TimeFrom'];
                            $consLunchOut = $schedule['LunchOut'];
                            $consLunchIn = $schedule['LunchIn'];
                            $consTimeOut = $schedule['TimeTo']; 
                        }
                }
        }

    ]
```

Comment: so, what is the result?

Comment: I am still waiting too because I always process around 600 raw attendance data....

Comment: you can use `$this->db->limit(10);`

Comment: this prompts me "Exception: [] operator not supported for strings"

Answer (score 0):

result_array() always return array, so you have to use row() or just use $data['schedule'] as array

```
$data['schedule'][0]['TimeFrom'];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want single row of data please use $row_array().

```
function retrieve_Sched($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('schedule');
    $this->db->where('EmpID',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

Comment: then how can I access it in my controller?

Comment: $this->model_name->retrieve_Sched($id);

Comment: just change in your model.$query->result_array(); to $query->row_array();

Comment: this gave me "Illegal string offset 'TimeFrom' " error

Comment: print_r($data['schedule']); than check you get anyone data in $data['schedule'];

Comment: As I said earlier in my comment that there's a data reflected the underlying problem now was it becomes empty when I passed it on variables....